# How is my HTML <image> element being interpreted as an <img> element?

Tags: html, dom, web-standards

I recently stumbled the use of an `<image>` element in a codebase. In latest Chrome, FF, and back to IE9 (didn't test 8 or below) - this element is rendered as an `<img>` element. I begin to dive into this, for I was not even sure where an `<image>` tag was coming from, and I found no reference as this being a valid or used tag *anywhere* e.g. per [w3 img tag docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-img-element.html#the-img-element) and [MDN `<img>` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) - there is no reference to an `<image>` tag at all.

Using Chrome as an example and the [Constructing the Object Model](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model?hl=en)
 as a reference, when inspecting my `<image>` => `<img>` element, I see that it is indeed interpreted as an `HTMLImageElement`.

I then had crazy thoughts that some voodoo is going on with the constructor being that of `HTMLImageElement`, perhaps some unspoken pattern I'm totally oblivious to, so I tried an experiment with an [`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a) element (which is an `HTMLAnchorElement`) but the following failed with no conversion: `<anchor href="">` `!--` `<a href="">`

Is there something I am fundamentally unaware of here? Where is this `<image>` => `<img>` conversion coming from?

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/oz971tqb/) - demo

---

Looking even further into this - I initially suspected this could be a browser "thing" but unable to find any source where this could be confirmed. I then used the [w3 Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to actually parse the explicit markup - but the results were not what I was expecting. Using an `<image>` element and the experimental `<anchor>` element - I get the following...

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- not seeing a way to fork this - here is the input -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>I thought I knew something about HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <image src="//sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png?v=6f86a5fa447f">
    <anchor href="#">anchor</anchor>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Where I get an explicit `<anchor>` not allowed, and `<img>` must have an `alt` attribute message. I would imagine this validator is browser-agnostic - if so, how could it be assumed there is a relation between `<image>` and `<img>`? Does this also assume this is potentially *not* a browser specific concern?

Comment: Wow nice find on the dupe - however - how is this not documented _anywhere_? Even the answers on the linked question are slightly subjective. Literally spent more time searching than I'd care to admit.

Comment: You say there is no documentation anywhere, but there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image

Comment: @MrLister nice find and thanks for sharing that!